# Any differentiated base on the place const used

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++: const reference, before vs after type-specifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694630/c-const-reference-before-vs-after-type-specifier)

Any different between these two definitions.

```
 1.   void foo(Animal const& dog){}

 2.   void foo(const Animal& dog){}
```

Comment: also [Why do some people prefer “T const&” over “const T&”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640446/why-do-some-people-prefer-t-const-over-const-t)

Comment: @LihO : Ohoo sorry. I searched for previous post. but couldn't find. anyway thank you.